# Proper (and safe) way to pressurize a vessel to around 70 kPa with gentle (~38* C) heat

Tags: pressure

I'm trying to force crystallization in a complex mixture by maintaining gentle pressure and heat. I'm thinking of using a Duran pressure plus bottle with a cap that has 2 GL-14 fittings, one attached to a compressed air pump and the other with a pressure gauge with release valve. I'm also considering Ace Glass pressure vessels. I don't have any experience working with pressurizing vessels and want people's input.

Thanks!

Comment: Atmospheric pressure is about 100 kPa, so you appear to want a pressure lower than atmospheric. Is this correct ?

Comment: Probably gauge I.e. about 0.7 barg, so 1.7 bara (absolute). I've never seen crystallisation induced by pressure though. Cooling by vacuum or vacuum distillation,  yes. Pressure, no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order internal pressure resistance to expect from laboratory glassware?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118576/order-internal-pressure-resistance-to-expect-from-laboratory-glassware)